# Java POST request to ASP.NET fails, C# works

Tags: java, post, asp.net-web-api, httpurlconnection

I have an ASP.NET Web API2 application where the controller has:

```
    public class LicenseController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("license")]
        [HttpPost]
        public XmlDocument PostLicense([FromBody] XmlDocument inputStream)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<root/>");
            return doc;
        }
}
```

And if I POST from a C# app, it receives the request and returns the "root/>":

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<david><shirley/></david>";

            Uri httpSite = new Uri(phoneHomeUri + "/license");
            WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(httpSite);
            wreq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            wreq.PreAuthenticate = true;
            wreq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            wreq.Method = "POST";
            wreq.ContentType = "text/xml";

            Stream request = wreq.GetRequestStream();
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
            request.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) wreq.GetResponse();

            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, encode);
            string s = readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But when I try the same thing in Java (below), while the "" returns correctly, the inputStream parameter in "[FromBody] XmlDocument inputStream" is null.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(phoneHomeUri + "/license").openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/xml");

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
writer.write(xml);
writer.flush();


InputStream result = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

I've tried changing lots of the settings on the Java code that makes the call. Why is it not getting the XML posted up to the web app controller?

thanks - dave

Comment: Try calling `writer.flush()` after you write the XML.

Comment: @VGR - good catch. But I added that and it still gives me a null on the ASP.NET side. Note to others, I have added this to the code above.

Comment: Does removing the accept-charset property from the request make a difference?

Comment: @VGR - still coming in as a null. I also tried setting the Content-Type to "text/plain" - still no luck.

Comment: What about a Content-Type of `text/xml; charset="UTF-8"`?  (I don't expect that to help but it's worth a try.)

Comment: @VGR - yep worth a try. Unfortunately still didn't work.

Comment: @DavidThielen still not working ?